# SQL Server replace last number to zero in decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

In SQL Server 2016, I have a column of type `decimal(16, 3)`. When I insert from C# code, I pass the decimal value like `1.234`. This value is saved in the database like `1.230`. SQL Server replaces the last number (4 in this case) with a 0. How to avoid this?

Comment: Can you post your C# code (with your insert) and your DB definition of that column?

Comment: What is the datatype of the C# code?

Comment: I wrote, column has data type `decimal(16,3)`. Property in C#: `public decimal Engine { get; set; }`. Insert: `public void Create(Data.Models.Car car)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(car.Customer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            dbContext.Car.Add(car);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }`
Looks like value has been rounded

Answer (score 0):

Something in the chain of operations must not have the datatype specified as `decimal(16,3)`

See this example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( c DECIMAL(16,3) )

INSERT INTO @t ( c )
VALUES ( 1.234 -- c - decimal(16, 3)
    )

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Yields: 1.234